# Java's PriorityQueue showing unexpected behavior for duplicate keys added with higher priority

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue, binary-heap

I was trying to implement a slightly modified version of the Djikstra's algorithm using the PriorityQueue class for the priority queue. I came across a weird behavior which I couldn't find an explanation for anywhere. I have my suspicions for this behavior but would like to know what others think of it. Could some one explain why the PriorityQueue behaves as it does below:

Since the standard algorithm involves decreasing a node's weight during a 'relax' operation, it would mean fetching the handle to a node and decreasing its weight (I am aware of the method where you back the queue up with a hashmap but this is an experiment). This method involves simply adding another copy of the node into the PriorityQueue. The duplicates are simply ignored after a node has been processed once. The problem however with such an implementation is that the PriorityQueue behaves in a undefined way for duplicates added subsequently. Here's a snippet showing the same:

```
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public class PriorityQueueTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] weight = new int[]{1, 2, 3};

        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(weight.length, (a, b) -> weight[a] - weight[b]);        
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
            pq.add(i);

        //change weight of node '1' from 2 to 0
        weight[1] = 0;
        //add duplicate node '1'. Note that this time weight 0 by the comparator.
        pq.add(1);

        while(!pq.isEmpty())
            System.out.println(pq.remove());
    }    
}
```

With the weight of node '1' decreased and its higher priority subsequently, one would expect the nodes to be removed in the order:

```
1
1
0
2
```

The actual result is however different:

```
0
1
1
2
```

Also note that if I just work with nodes 0 and 1 (changing the for loop in the above to

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
```

), then the expected order of

```
1
1
0
```

is the same as the actual order!

You can play with adding more nodes and changing some other node's weight which again gives this unexpected behavior sometimes depending on the number of nodes added after the first duplicate.

My suspicion is when adding a duplicate, the heapify operation is performed during which the old key might have broken the heap invariant (having a higher priority and yet potentially being misplaced after the weight update) and any subsequent heapifies on that old node might leave the heap in a inconsistent state. Thoughts?????

Comment: Thoughts? Yeah, you shouldn't be changing the priorities of things inside the heap. It's like changing the hashcode of a map key, it breaks stuff.

Comment: If you want to change the priority of an item in the PQ you have to remove it first and replace it afterwards. 'Duplicate keys added with higher priority' embodies a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're changing weights, but not re-ordering the queue. In your example you add three items with values 0, 1, and 2. `PriorityQueue` uses a binary heap internally. The heap that's created is:

```
      1
    /   \
   2     3
```

You then change the value of the `2` node to `0`, resulting in this invalid heap:

```
      1
    /   \
   0     3
```

Now you have an invalid heap. In a binary min heap, every node must be smaller that or equal to its parent. But in this case, `1` is the parent of `0`. From this point forward, any operations you do on the heap will produce unpredictable results.

The Java `PriorityQueue` doesn't lend itself to changing node priorities. It doesn't have a method to remove an arbitrary element, and it doesn't give you access to the backing store, so you can't write your own. If you want the ability to change node priorities, you'll have to find a priority queue implementation that supports it, or roll your own.

Comment: Yeah, I suspected the same. However bummer, I couldn't find that one small point in that linked existing duplicate question that has the same explanation I was looking for. Anyway thanks for answering regardless!